# Oracle Advanced Replication - Remote Packages Under Permanent Access

Tags: oracle, database-replication, oracle11gr2

As descriped in the documentation it seems to be possible to replicate packages (spec and body) beside other database objects. But what will happen if the packages of the remote database (slave) are under permanent access? Is a replication under such circumstance possible too? I didn't find any hint in the documentation.

Many thanks in advance